# FrameLayout creates another ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-framelayout

I have an ActionBar which is shown in some activities.
Unfortunately, in one of them, I use a FrameLayout and the FrameLayout creates another ActionBar. How can I remove this second ActionBar ?

[image]
[image]
Bellow, the layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/browser_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- activity view -->
    <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame">

        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFindSelected"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/selection" />

            <ListView
                    android:id="@android:id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/browser_left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The code of the Toolbar for the DrawerLayout :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

My theme :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

My theme (For api 21+)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try using a ui automator view from the tools under sdk. Grab a snap shot and check the ui elements on the screen. It does not look like you have another actionbar from the screen shot

Comment: You are right. When I remove this line "<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>" the two bar disappear.

With the ui automator view, I see that there is a duplication. But I don't know where...

Comment: are you setting toolbar as actionbar in your activity. seems to be the height of toolbar do you see two views in the ui automator??

Comment: Yes, in my activity I set "toolbar" as actionbar.
And yes, there are two views :o
Screenshot : http://oi57.tinypic.com/abjuky.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...

I was using a FragmentManager in a wrong way. The result was a duplication of some of my elements.
More informations here (on the second answer) : http://www.codedisqus.com/0zmgWXjjXj/android-fragment-duplicate-objects-in-layout.html